# AWS CDK Python WAF Multiple IPSets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-waf

i'm creating multiple IPSets in aws cdk with python, and i wonder if there is a better way to write this in python.

Here is how i wrote this:

```
        ip_set01 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
        scope_=self,
        id='WAFTESTIPSET01',
        scope='REGIONAL',
        description='Block test01',
        addresses= [],
        ip_address_version="IPV4",
    )
    
    
    
    ip_set02 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
        scope_=self,
        id='WAFTESTIPSET02',
        scope='REGIONAL',
        description='Block test02',
        addresses= [],
        ip_address_version="IPV6",
    )
    
    ip_set03 = wafv2.CfnIPSet(
        scope_=self,
        id='WAFTESTIPSET03',
        scope='REGIONAL',
        description='Block test03',
        addresses= [],
        ip_address_version="IPV4",
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write something like this:

```py
ip_sets = [
    wafv2.CfnIPSet(
        scope_=self,
        id=f"WAFTESTIPSET0{i}",
        scope="REGIONAL",
        description=f"Block test0{i}",
        addresses=[],
        ip_address_version="IPV4",
    )
    for i in range(1, 4)
]
```

If you really want to use different ip address versions, then you probably need to use a map:

```py
ip_map = {
    "01": "IPV4",
    "02": "IPV6",
    "03": "IPV4"
}
ip_sets = [
    wafv2.CfnIPSet(
        scope_=self,
        id=f"WAFTESTIPSET{key}",
        scope="REGIONAL",
        description=f"Block test{key}",
        addresses=[],
        ip_address_version=ip_map[key],
    )
    for key in ip_map
]
```